# When using Active Admin, how do you make the default rails actions disappear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I've implemented active admin, but I was wondering how to get the default controller actions of "new, update, edit, destroy" to go away. Right now what I did was remove the actions from the controller, deleted the corresponding views. But if I go to like localhost:3000/pages/new I get something like this: "Unknown action The action 'new' could not be found for PagesController". What I'd really like is for that to redirect to the admin login page. But I'm unsure how to go about that. I tried this:

```
match '*path' => redirect('/admin')
```

but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `resources :pages` in your routes.rb file.